# MySQL 8.0.1 mysql.plugin doesn't exist

Tags: mysql

Had extracted MySQL Zip file to my Windows 10_x64 machine, MySQL Version `mysqld.exe  Ver 8.0.11 for Win64 on x86_64 (MySQL Community Server - GPL)`

After trying to do several config on my.ini such as base_dir, data_dir etc. Start mysqld.exe --initialize-insecure and passed. After that trying to start mysqld.exe --console and got some serious problem. Here they are

```
2018-06-28T04:47:48.238801Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010915] [Server] 'NO_ZERO_DATE', 'NO_ZERO_IN_DATE' and 'ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO' sql modes should be used with strict mode. They will be merged with strict mode in a future release.
2018-06-28T04:47:48.238982Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] C:\Users\root\Workspace\root\idk\mysqld\bin\mysqld.exe (mysqld 8.0.11) starting as process 2712
mysqld: Table 'mysql.plugin' doesn't exist
2018-06-28T04:47:51.723643Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010735] [Server] Can't open the mysql.plugin table. Please run mysql_upgrade to create it.
2018-06-28T04:47:52.004285Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010015] [Repl] Gtid table is not ready to be used. Table 'mysql.gtid_executed' cannot be opened.
2018-06-28T04:47:53.092887Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2018-06-28T04:47:53.103151Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010441] [Server] Failed to open optimizer cost constant tables
2018-06-28T04:47:53.107156Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-013129] [Server] A message intended for a client cannot be sent there as no client-session is attached. Therefore, we're sending the information to the error-log instead: MY-001146 - Table 'mysql.component' doesn't exist
2018-06-28T04:47:53.113269Z 0 [Warning] [MY-013129] [Server] A message intended for a client cannot be sent there as no client-session is attached. Therefore, we're sending the information to the error-log instead: MY-003543 - The mysql.component table is missing or has an incorrect definition.
2018-06-28T04:47:53.120634Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-011071] [Server] unknown variable 'default-character-set=utf8'
2018-06-28T04:47:53.122638Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010952] [Server] The privilege system failed to initialize correctly. If you have upgraded your server, make sure you're executing mysql_upgrade to correct the issue.
2018-06-28T04:47:53.126213Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2018-06-28T04:47:54.110844Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] C:\Users\root\Workspace\root\idk\mysqld\bin\mysqld.exe: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.11)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
```

Have following some community guideline such as add configuration at my.ini as bellow

```
innodb_lock_wait_timeout = 50
innodb_flush_method=normal
```

Nothing works.

Assume my directory such as bellow

```
basedir="C:/Users/root/Workspace/root/idk/mysqld/"
datadir="C:/Users/root/Workspace/root/idk/mysqldata"
```

I've looking for SO post and no one solution works for me. Please help. Thanks